# Where does git store its reflog?

Tags: git, git-reflog

I know that compressed version of `reflog` is stored in  `.git/packed-refs`
but where is actual reflog is located and how git restores history when one types `git reflog` ?

Comment: `.git/packed-refs` contains normal references, not a reflog.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reflogs are in `.git/logs/<refname>`.  For example, for a branch named `master` (eg, `refs/heads/master`) then you would want `.git/logs/refs/heads/master`.

`HEAD`, of course, is anomalous, and is `.git/logs/HEAD`.